# Spring 3.2.9 constructor injecting collection fails with NoSuchMethodException

Tags: spring, list, constructor-injection

I am injecting a @Qualified collection of singleton beans into a constructor. Many of the beans being used have a single @Autowired parameterized constructor and no default constructor. However, Spring seems intent on always using the default constructor, resulting in a NoSuchMethodException. Is this a limitation of Spring 3.2.9? I could not find anything in the documentation indicating this was invalid.

The following is the abridged, redacted code that declares a bean to be discovered by its common interface:

```
@IsPersistence
@Component("SomeComponent")
@Qualifier("category")
public class SomeComponent extends CommonBase implements CommonInterface {

    @Autowired
    public SomeComponent (
            @Qualifier("SomeOtherComponent") SomeOtherComponent component) {
        super(component);
    }

}
```

A redacted configuration that consumes this bean is as follows:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"some.package"}})
public class SomeConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "AnotherBean")
    @Autowired
    public AnotherBean anotherBean(
            @Qualifier("category") final List<CommonInterface > objects) {
        return new AnotherBean(objects);
    }

}
```

When wiring up this class the following stack trace is produced:

```
2018-01-31 07:19:28,618 ERROR err:105 main - java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: some.package.SomeComponent .<init>()
2018-01-31 07:19:28,618 ERROR err:105 main -    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2715)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,618 ERROR err:105 main -    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:1987)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,618 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:78)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,618 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1030)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,618 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:983)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,618 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,618 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,618 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,618 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,618 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,618 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,618 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:917)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,618 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:818)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,618 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,618 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:817)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,618 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:745)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,618 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:469)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,618 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1055)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,618 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:951)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,618 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,618 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,618 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,618 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,618 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,634 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,634 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:917)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,634 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:860)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,634 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,634 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:817)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,634 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:745)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,634 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:469)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,634 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1055)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,634 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:951)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,634 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,634 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,634 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,634 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,634 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,634 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,634 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1121)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,634 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:674)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,634 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,634 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:120)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,634 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,634 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,634 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:248)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,634 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,634 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,634 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:122)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,650 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,650 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,650 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,650 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,650 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,650 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,650 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,650 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,650 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,650 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,650 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,650 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,650 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,650 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,650 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,650 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,650 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,650 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,650 ERROR err:105 main -    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,650 ERROR err:105 main -    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,650 ERROR err:105 main -    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,650 ERROR err:105 main -    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
2018-01-31 07:19:28,650 ERROR err:105 main -    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

As to why not use the current version, this is a system in production that has a reputation for very slow adoption of newer versions of Spring. Working on this, but the problem is immediate and the adoption will take considerably more time.

I have worked around this problem by coding the bean construction in a factory method on the configuration. However, there are quite a few of these beans and it would probably be best to handle this via annotation instead of directly on the configuration classes.

Comment: why not use the current version?

Comment: Also share the stacktrace

Comment: @karl-koster , please show minimal code which fails

Comment: @walsh - commented a the end of the edited post

Comment: @Rakesh - stacktrace added

Comment: @AntonTupy - minimum code example included

Answer (score 2):

The *Spring version 3.x* had some constraints while using `@Autowired` on `@Configuration` classes. Check out the [`docs`](http://@Configuration%20classes%20must%20have%20a%20default/no-arg%20constructor%20and%20may%20not%20use%20@Autowired%20constructor%20parameters.%20Any%20nested%20configuration%20classes%20must%20be%20static).

> @Configuration classes must have a default/no-arg constructor and may not use @Autowired constructor parameters.

Besides `@Autowired` annotations can be applied to class constructors only with the realease of [`Spring v4.3`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-autowired-annotation) and later.

As a matter of fact its not even necessary if there is only one *constructor* defined.

> As of Spring Framework 4.3, an @Autowired annotation on such a constructor is no longer necessary if the target bean only defines one constructor to begin with. However, if several constructors are available, at least one must be annotated to teach the container which one to use.

So the issue with your code is the old Spring version that doesn't entertain `@Autowired` over class contructors.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am glad I don't have to pound my head against the wall anymore.

Comment: Glad i could help :)

Comment: I had a look at the JavaDoc for the Autowired annotations and it says the following: 
*Marks a constructor, field, setter method or config method as to be autowired by Spring's dependency injection facilities.
Only one constructor (at max) of any given bean class may carry this annotation, indicating the constructor to autowire when used as a Spring bean. Such a constructor does not have to be public.*

This has been around since 2.5. So constructor autowiring is available.

Comment: @AbdullahKahn, I think there is a misunderstanding on your comment. The constructor is not on the configuration class. It is on a "normal" Spring managed bean.